# Excel: Running a conditional if and only if data is in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently working on a spreadsheet that logs and tracks data for medical screenings. I'm attempting to make it as user-friendly as possible for any of the clinicians to use. What I want to achieve is to:

Have a conditional that highlights a cell when there is no text (`B2`)
Only highlight that cell when there is text present in another cell (`A2`)
And clear the highlight once text is entered into that cell (`B2=notempty`) `=LEN(B1)=0` is what I am using now.

What I'd like to achieve is to have the cell run this conditional `IF AND ONLY IF` cell `A2` is filled with data. I'm pretty new to formulas so any help would be awesome right now I'm fiddling around with:

```
=NOT(IF($I$2=0,(LEN(J2:J13)=0)))
```

Only half of this is working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site. If I understand correctly, you want `B2` highlighted only if `A2` has text AND `B2` is empty. Correct? What if `A2` has a number entered? Also, I don't understand what the formula (`=NOT(IF($I$2=0,(LEN(J2:J13)=0)))`) has to do with this question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Correct! That's the conditional I was fooling around with in my limited capacity lol. If A2 has a number entered and B2 is empty, B2 should be highlighted. If A2 and B2 both have text then both should be free of highlights.

Comment: What if both are empty? No highlight?

Comment: Correct! If both are empty then there should be no highlights. I think I have it figured out using a number of conditionals. But now there is a whole new issue! I can't get the conditionals to toggle out of absolute reference -_-

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "toggle". If you are meaning *change when you drag the formula to another cell*, then they are doing what absolute references do. They stay the same no matter where you put them.

Comment: It was the whole "press F4 to cycle through the reference types" thing. I did manage to get it to work but now I'm having an entirely new issue that I wasn't having last night when I'd saved it -_-. I'm running multiple conditionals and one cell, in particular, is referencing a cell that I do NOT have in the formula. It's extremely irksome and I'm not sure why it is doing that at all. Part of the conditional for F2 is =H2>0. I use this to revert F2 back to its original state when text is entered into H2.

Comment: When I enter text however it does nothing. It does, however revert back to its original state when I enter text into J2. I have checked each conditional, and not one is referencing cell J2, I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I read and understand your question correctly but part of the problem may be using the "len" function for a range, but not formatting it correctly. 
After entering a range based formula, select the cell and enter "Control+shift+enter". Excel will enclose the formula in braces {} and denote it as an array.

If this works, all is good, if not you could also consider replacing the range (LEN(J2:J13)=0) portion of your formula to an if-then function triggering off a "sumproduct" for the cells you are interested in.

I.e.: =IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:D10))=0,"Do something","Do something else")

Good luck : -)

Comment: For conditional formatting better to use a formula without if

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional format formula needs to make two logical checks, one to check cell `A2` for not being blank and the other to check `B2` for being blank.

To check make multiple logical checks use the [`AND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) function. It uses the syntax of `AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)`.

Then use `A2<>""` to check that `A2` is not blank and `ISBLANK` to check if `B2` is blank. If both criteria are met, then it triggers the conditional formatting you have set.

```
=AND(A2<>"", ISBLANK(B2))
```

It works like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was a much more elegant solution to my current one!